# Integrate swagger codegen into an existing project

Tags: node.js, swagger

I work into a existing nodeJS project and I would like to use swagger codegen to automate the documentation.

Currently I write the swagger doc after to have code and there is always a time lag between dev and production....

I find two solutions. The first generate the node js projet and after you code inside, but my project have one year and lot of code...

The second solution is to write a syntax in my code and automate the documentation after with command line but this solution don't use yaml and my actual doc is to write is Yaml...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If your existing node.js project uses [Express](https://expressjs.com/) as its web framework, you could consider using [swagger-spec-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-spec-express) which would enable you to simply annotate your existing express api with swagger info.